# How do I draw onto a CVPixelBufferRef that is planar/ycbcr/420f/yuv/NV12/not rgb?

Tags: ios, core-image, core-video, replaykit, core-media

I have received a `CMSampleBufferRef` from a system API that contains `CVPixelBufferRef`s that are not `RGBA` (linear pixels). The buffer contains planar pixels (such as `420f` aka `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` aka `yCbCr` aka `YUV`).

I would like to modify do some manipulation of this video data before sending it off to `VideoToolkit` to be encoded to `h264` (drawing some text, overlaying a logo, rotating the image, etc), but I'd like for it to be efficient and real-time. Buuuut planar image data looks suuuper messy to work with -- there's the chroma plane and the luma plane and they're different sizes and... Working with this on a byte level seems like a lot of work.

I could probably use a `CGContextRef` and just paint right on top of the pixels, but from what I can gather it only supports RGBA pixels. Any advice on how I can do this with as little data copying as possible, yet as few lines of code as possible?

Answer (score 5):

`CGBitmapContextRef` can only paint into something like `32ARGB`, correct. This means that you will want to create `ARGB` (or `RGBA`) buffers, and then find a way to very quickly transfer `YUV` pixels onto this `ARGB` surface. This recipe includes using `CoreImage`, a home-made `CVPixelBufferRef` through a pool, a `CGBitmapContextRef` referencing your home made pixel buffer, and then recreating a `CMSampleBufferRef` resembling your input buffer, but referencing your output pixels. In other words,

1. Fetch the incoming pixels into a `CIImage`.
2. Create a `CVPixelBufferPool` with the pixel format and output dimensions you are creating. You don't want to create `CVPixelBuffer`s without a pool in real time: you will run out of memory if your producer is too fast; you'll fragment your RAM as you won't be reusing buffers; and it's a waste of cycles.
3. Create a `CIContext` with the default constructor that you'll share between buffers. It contains no external state, but documentation says that recreating it on every frame is very expensive.
4. On incoming frame, create a new pixel buffer. Make sure to use an allocation threshold so you don't get runaway RAM usage.
5. Lock the pixel buffer
6. Create a bitmap context referencing the bytes in the pixel buffer
7. Use CIContext to render the planar image data into the linear buffer
8. Perform your app-specific drawing in the CGContext!
9. Unlock the pixel buffer
10. Fetch the timing info of the original sample buffer
11. Create a `CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef` by asking the pixel buffer for its exact format
12. Create a sample buffer for the pixel buffer. Done!

Here's a sample implementation, where I have chosen 32ARGB as the image format to work with, as that's something that both `CGBitmapContext` and `CoreVideo` enjoys working with on iOS:

```
{
    CGPixelBufferPoolRef *_pool;
    CGSize _poolBufferDimensions;
}
- (void)_processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)inputBuffer
{
    // 1. Input data
    CVPixelBufferRef inputPixels = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(inputBuffer);
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:inputPixels];

    // 2. Create a new pool if the old pool doesn't have the right format.
    CGSize bufferDimensions = {CVPixelBufferGetWidth(inputPixels), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(inputPixels)};
    if(!_pool || !CGSizeEqualToSize(bufferDimensions, _poolBufferDimensions)) {
        if(_pool) {
            CFRelease(_pool);
        }
        OSStatus ok0 = CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(NULL,
            NULL, // pool attrs
            (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(@{
                (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
                (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: @(bufferDimensions.width),
                (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: @(bufferDimensions.height),
            }), // buffer attrs
            &_pool
        );
        _poolBufferDimensions = bufferDimensions;
        assert(ok0 == noErr);
    }

    // 4. Create pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferRef outputPixels;
    OSStatus ok1 = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBufferWithAuxAttributes(NULL,
        _pool,
        (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{
            // Opt to fail buffer creation in case of slow buffer consumption
            // rather than to exhaust all memory.
            (__bridge id)kCVPixelBufferPoolAllocationThresholdKey: @20
        }, // aux attributes
        &outputPixels
    );
    if(ok1 == kCVReturnWouldExceedAllocationThreshold) {
        // Dropping frame because consumer is too slow
        return;
    }
    assert(ok1 == noErr);

    // 5, 6. Graphics context to draw in
    CGColorSpaceRef deviceColors = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    OSStatus ok2 = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(outputPixels, 0);
    assert(ok2 == noErr);
    CGContextRef cg = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(outputPixels), // bytes
        CVPixelBufferGetWidth(inputPixels), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(inputPixels), // dimensions
        8, // bits per component
        CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(outputPixels), // bytes per row
        deviceColors, // color space
        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst // bitmap info
    );
    CFRelease(deviceColors);
    assert(cg != NULL);

    // 7
    [_imageContext render:inputImage toCVPixelBuffer:outputPixels];

    // 8. DRAW
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cg, 0.5, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(cg, kCGTextFill);
    NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world" attributes:NULL];
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)text);
    CTLineDraw(line, cg);
    CFRelease(line);

    // 9. Unlock and stop drawing
    CFRelease(cg);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(outputPixels, 0);

    // 10. Timings
    CMSampleTimingInfo timingInfo;
    OSStatus ok4 = CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(inputBuffer, 0, &timingInfo);
    assert(ok4 == noErr);

    // 11. VIdeo format
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoFormat;
    OSStatus ok5 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(NULL, outputPixels, &videoFormat);
    assert(ok5 == noErr);

    // 12. Output sample buffer
    CMSampleBufferRef outputBuffer;
    OSStatus ok3 = CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(NULL, // allocator
        outputPixels, // image buffer 
        YES, // data ready
        NULL, // make ready callback
        NULL, // make ready refcon
        videoFormat,
        &timingInfo, // timing info
        &outputBuffer // out
    );
    assert(ok3 == noErr);

    [_consumer consumeSampleBuffer:outputBuffer];
    CFRelease(outputPixels);
    CFRelease(videoFormat);
    CFRelease(outputBuffer);
}
```

Comment: please give an example in Swift 4

Comment: is it really fast? because I tried next and it eats a lot of cpu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066195/what-is-the-best-way-to-record-a-video-with-augmented-reality

Comment: _pool, _poolBufferDimensions of which type are they?

Comment: @user924 no sorry, way too much work for me :( it should pretty much translate line-by-line; please post if you do so! Also, I added types for the two ivars at the top of the code block.

Comment: I don't need swift solutions anymore, I decided to use opencv (c++) in ojective-c++ class (.mm) and directly process pixelbuffer using pointer (without copying, converting anything)

Comment: Do you guys have a solution for BroadCast Extension? I used this code on Sample Handler to compress the CMSampleBuffer but it crashes in seconds.